# Zoom Search Engine-like search engine, but for Linux/UNIX

Tags: linux, search, indexing, search-engine

I recently found the [Zoom Search Engine](http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/), which struck me as quite interesting, since its software allows for easy decoupling of the indexing process and the searching process.

In other words, you run the indexer on your local machine, and then you upload this index plus the PHP files using it to search them to your webserver.

So your webserver doesn't have to do the indexing. I have a host in a shared environment where it's best to use as few resources as possible, so this would be great to me. Moreover, I have a mostly unused small server at home (this is not the webserver I have) that I could use for indexing purposes.

However, it runs Linux, SSH only, so the Zoom Search Engine is not an option.

Is there something that has the same principle as the Zoom Search Engine (index locally, upload index + PHP to website), but available for a command line Linux environment?

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to have a look at [OpenSearchServer](http://www.open-search-server.com/) . A lucene based Search Engine. Easy to setup, mature and stable.

For Your requirements :

OpenSearchServer supports Linux and windows platform.

SSH is enough for running OpenSearchServer remotely.

You can crawl the website locally and update the index (The data directory of OpenSearchServer ) to your remote machine through replication or through FTP.For larger index replication is the best option.

It has an PHP client library so that you can easily enable search in your existing or new application.

Answer (score 2):

SPHINX SEARCH SERVER: http://sphinxsearch.com/

Absolutely fulfilling all your needs and also used by some popular shops like Craigslist, MySQL etc.

PHP is very inherent to Sphinx. All the interfaces are in PHP with the actual engine written in C++. Its blazing fast.

I myself use Solr/Lucene but I give Sphinx +1 for your tasks.